# What is the best way to keep debug code out of the release build?

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I have an Android app with some debug code that I only want to be included in debug builds and not in the release build. I've wrapped the debug code in an if statement that checks for `BuildConfig.DEBUG`, but I'm not sure if this is enough to ensure that the code is removed from the release build.

What is the best way to ensure that debug code is not included in the release build? Do I need to make changes to the Proguard rules?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your current approach should be the best way.